# filterContentForSearchText method is getting an error

Tags: uisearchbar

I am trying to add a search bar to my app. I am following the AppCoda tutorial here: http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/ When the user starts to type in the search bar, the app stops running at the line:

```
NSArray *resultsFromTheSearch = [profileNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
```

Here is the full method

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope: (NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    NSMutableArray *profileNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (PFUser *user in self.profiles) {
        [profileNames addObject:user.username];
    }

    NSArray *resultsFromTheSearch = [profileNames filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    for (NSString *nameStr in resultsFromTheSearch) {
        PFQuery *userQuerySearch = [PFUser query];
        [userQuerySearch whereKey:@"username" equalTo:nameStr];
        [userQuerySearch findObjectsInBackground];
    }
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in your predicate. Since, you have already added names in array, your predicate should be

```
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self contains[c] %@", searchText];
```